# Having trouble putting 4 images in a 2 by 2 square to fit on half of the page in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I've tried everything. Need Help PLEASE! Wanting to get the wire frame images in a 2 by 2 on the right side of the page. Being able to be responsive at the sametime.

any help will be appreciated soo much!

```css
   
.flex-container {
    display: -webkit-flex;
 display: flex;
 -webkit-flex-direction: row;
 column-count:2;
 width: 100%;
 height: 25%;
    
}


.flex-item1 {
    
    font-family: sans-serif;
    width: 400px;
    height:auto;
    padding:50px; 
    margin: 0,0,40px,0;
    text-align: justify;
    
    
}

.flex-item2 {
    
    font-family: sans-serif;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    align-items:center;
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    
}


h1{
    
    text-align: center;
}

h2 {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding-left:200%;
    padding-top: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    
}
.wireframe-container{
    
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto; 
    padding: 0px; 
    text-align:center;
    
    
}

.wire{
    
    position:relative; 
    display:inline-block;
    width:30%; max-width:180px; 
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin:0 10px; 
    padding-left:10px;
   
    
}


.desc {
    
    margin: 10px;
    padding-bottom:100px;
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Assignment 1.css"/>
 
<title>Page Title</title>

</head>


<body>
    
  <img src="ass 1 background.png" class="responsive-image">  
        
<div class="flex-container">
  
    <div class="flex-item1">
    Creating an app designed for mobile devices (smart phones and tablets). Able to use the smart phones camera or tablet to view the picture in real-time. Jager is centred around the old-style game of I Spy/Scavenger hunt played usually by kids. This focus would be part of the Mahuki Gamelab team. Creating games used for education in fun ways to help get children involved in the seasonal museum exhibitions.
        <br><br>
       <h1>Abstract</h1> 
        <br><br> 
    To create a game for mobile devices, tablets and smart phones. An app that uses augmented reality technology to involve users in the environment around them. The game is a scavenger hunt / I SPY type of game played using your smart phone or tablet’s built-in camera to view the world through. The app will generate an object to make the user search for from a list of pre-programmed items and paths. The app will give users a hint or a clue to the general area or direction of the object. A timer and a score will be used to create competition between children.  Students should be able to compare scores and time, from a type of leader board system. Animations and buttons will be projected onto user’s screens in real time off the objects. Users can gain achievements and badges for doing certain task also. 
    </div>
  
    

<div class="flex-item2">
     
    <h2>Wireframes</h2>
    
          
     <div class="wireframes-container">
        
         <div class="wire">
            
         <a target="_blank" href="wire1.png">
           <img src="wire1.png"style="width:10em; height:15em;" />
             </a>
           <div class="desc">phone</div>
         
    
        
    
    
        <a target="_blank" href="wire2.png">
            <img src="wire2.png"style="width:15em; height:15em;" />
            </a>
            <div class="desc">tablet</div>
         
        

        
    
        <a target="_blank" href="wire4.png">
         <img src="wire4.png"style="width:10em; height:15em;" />
            </a>
        <div class="desc">AR mode</div>
        
    
        
        
        <a target="_blank" href="wire3.png">
         <img src="wire3.png"style="width:15em; height:15em;" />
        <div class="desc">AR mode</div>
            </a>
        </div>
        
        </div>
    
    </div>
   
    </div>
 
</body>




</html>
```

Comment: Can you reduce this down to the minimal amount to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Use css `display: grid` http://gridbyexample.com

Comment: Beware of `display:grid`, browser support is sparse http://caniuse.com/#search=grid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what you're trying to achieve; it's very simple with the use of `display:table` and `display:table-cell`. Using these properties gives great browser support as well (IE 8+). Check out this bin:
http://jsbin.com/wedapulixa/edit?html,output

You'll likely need to change how the images are sized based on your needs, but I'll leave that up to you. You could utilize `div`s with the `background-image` and `background-size` properties instead of `img`s depending on your needs.

Comment: Thank you that worked. Just gotta do my own tweaking :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you use Bootstrap? It is very usefull to order elements in DOM.

Just divide the elements in columns, and if you need to put some elements in the same line use the class "row"

Answer (score 0):

You can get items to lie next to each other using `display: inline-block` and then adjust the width of the container so that only two of the images have space. I also had to remove the max-width property on .wire. By doing that and then wrapping each wire-frame image in a div.grid-item you get this (note the two extra css rules I added at the bottom):

```css
.flex-container {
    display: -webkit-flex;
 display: flex;
 -webkit-flex-direction: row;
 column-count:2;
 width: 100%;
 height: 25%;
    
}


.flex-item1 {
    
    font-family: sans-serif;
    width: 400px;
    height:auto;
    padding:50px; 
    margin: 0,0,40px,0;
    text-align: justify;
    
    
}

.flex-item2 {
    
    font-family: sans-serif;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    align-items:center;
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    
}


h1{
    
    text-align: center;
}

h2 {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding-left:200%;
    padding-top: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    
}
.wireframe-container{
    
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto; 
    padding: 0px; 
    text-align:center;
    
    
}

.wire{
    
    position:relative; 
    display:inline-block;
    width:30%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin:0 10px; 
    padding-left:10px;
   
    
}


.desc {
    
    margin: 10px;
    padding-bottom:100px;
    
}


.wire {
  width: 26em;
}

.grid-item {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<img src="ass 1 background.png" class="responsive-image">


<div class="flex-container">

  <div class="flex-item1">
    Creating an app designed for mobile devices (smart phones and tablets). Able to use the smart phones camera or tablet to view the picture in real-time. Jager is centred around the old-style game of I Spy/Scavenger hunt played usually by kids. This focus
    would be part of the Mahuki Gamelab team. Creating games used for education in fun ways to help get children involved in the seasonal museum exhibitions.
    <br><br>
    <h1>Abstract</h1>
    <br><br> To create a game for mobile devices, tablets and smart phones. An app that uses augmented reality technology to involve users in the environment around them. The game is a scavenger hunt / I SPY type of game played using your smart phone
    or tablet’s built-in camera to view the world through. The app will generate an object to make the user search for from a list of pre-programmed items and paths. The app will give users a hint or a clue to the general area or direction of the object.
    A timer and a score will be used to create competition between children. Students should be able to compare scores and time, from a type of leader board system. Animations and buttons will be projected onto user’s screens in real time off the objects.
    Users can gain achievements and badges for doing certain task also.
  </div>


  <div class="flex-item2">

    <h2>Wireframes</h2>


    <div class="wireframes-container">

      <div class="wire">
        <div class="grid-item">
          <a target="_blank" href="wire1.png">
            <img src="wire1.png" style="width:10em; height:15em;" />
          </a>
          <div class="desc">phone</div>
        </div>

        <div class="grid-item">
          <a target="_blank" href="wire2.png">
            <img src="wire2.png" style="width:15em; height:15em;" />
          </a>
          <div class="desc">tablet</div>
        </div>

        <div class="grid-item">
          <a target="_blank" href="wire4.png">
            <img src="wire4.png" style="width:10em; height:15em;" />
          </a>
          <div class="desc">AR mode</div>
        </div>

        <div class="grid-item">
          <a target="_blank" href="wire3.png">
            <img src="wire3.png" style="width:15em; height:15em;" />
            <div class="desc">AR mode</div>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```